# Getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO' When Attempting to Create Export File

Tags: sql-server, export-to-csv

I am trying to create an export file from a database view that I created.
I was able to successfully complete the steps to define the query and populate the temp tables but when I attempt to export the data to file I am receiving the error message

> 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TO'.

This is the complete error:

> 1:52:06 AM [ 2063] (15) Populate temp tables with values
> (AG16_RUN0020)
>
> 1:52:06 AM ERROR : Error (156) Error in AGRExecSql:
> Couldn't execute statement (156) when (25) Create export file: 42000
> [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax
> near the keyword 'TO'.:

I am using the following for the Create Export File step:

```
COPY TO EXPORT FILE ='DataFeed.txt',colsep=;, 
SELECT degree__1, huid__1,stage__1, f22_schooltag, status_effective_date__1,f21_effdt,last_name__1,first_name__1, middle_name__1, f20_other_last_, name__1,f1_prefix,  name_suffix__1,alias_name,client,date_of_birth__1,f3_birth_state,f4_birth_countr, gender__1,f5_marital_stat,ssn__1,f6_itin,f7_military_sta,f8_disabled_vet,us_citizenship__1,f17_citizen_sta,huit_country_code__1,country_of_citizenship__1,visa_type__1,f19_huit_visa_t,ethnicity__1,f9_ethnicity_w,f10_ethnicity_b,f11_ethnicity_a,f12_ethnicity_p,f13_ethnicity_a, f14_ethnicity_h,telephone__1, f18_primary_pho,f15_other_phone, f16_other_phone,    type__1,term__1,student_pk__2, student_pk__1,student_pk 
FROM $*hlptab25 
ORDER BY huid__1 ASC,last_name__1 ASC,first_name__1 ASC
```

I have tried to just use 'COPY TO' and 'COPY INTO FILE' but the syntax error still persists. I also put parenthesis around the whole SQL statement and that did not resolve the issue.

Has anyone encountered this before - if so how did you resolve it?
Thanks

Comment: Formatting and tags

Comment: TSQL has no "COPY" command. I suggest you simply search the internet for suggestions about exporting csv data from sql server using the tools you are most comfortable with.